# What is a better solution than adding dummy parameters to Funcs to make the signatures match?

Tags: c#

I have a method with an argument of type

```
Func<Color, Double, Color> colorFunc
```

This is useful because I can specify any of a number of functions and invent new ones ad-hoc.  My difficulty is that while nearly all the functions take an additional parameter (Double in this instance), some don't.  I have solved this by adding a 'dummy' optional parameter which is never used to to these functions.

Is this the best solution? What if I had mutiple functions with different numbers of parameters?  Should I even them all up with dummy parameters?

Comment: If the functions don't take three parameters, why are you not using `Func<Color, Color>` instead?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Because some do and some don't.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking.  Perhaps you could an example of what you are doing.  Why do you think they need the same number of parameters?

Comment: In my opinion the better solution would be to have multiple functions with different numbers of parameters since this would be the most readable method.

Comment: @descf then for the ones that do, use Func<T1,T2,T3> and those that don't, use Func<T1, T2>.  You haven't detailed any reason why that's not acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest moving from `Func<t>` delegates to a custom delegate type, in this case, for a couple reasons.

First, defaults

```
    public delegate Color HerpinateColor(Color initial, double count = double.NaN);
```

You can identify optional parameters and set their defaults.  But, what do in cases when the default value is the one passed in?  That brings me to the second benefit, *documentation!*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A method to reherpinate colors or something lol
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initial">An initial value for the <see cref="Color"/>
    /// to apply the reherpenation algorithm on.</param>
    /// <param name="count">(optional)The average herp of the derp.</param>
    /// <returns>A reherpenated <see cref="Color"/></returns>
    /// <remarks>Implementations should avoid fooing the bar if <paramref name="count"/>
    /// is <see cref="double.NaN"/>.</remarks>
    public delegate Color HerpinateColor(Color initial, double count = double.NaN);
```

Custom delegates can be documented.  Oh, sure, you can cram that into your method signature, but it won't show up in intellisense (or will be severely limited).

Funcs/actions are very useful, but using custom delegates still has a couple advantages over them.

---

OH, and you can still use lambdas, which means your API still has the same feel to implementors.

```
HerpinateColor derp = (initial, count) => double.IsNaN(count) ? 
                                                 Color.Multiply(initial, .5f) : 
                                                 Color.Multiply(initial, (float)count);
```